# Repainting NSBezierPath

Tags: objective-c, drawing, nsbezierpath

This is the way I'm painting a like-popover window with a bezier path. The BOOLEAN bAbajo makes the drawing window point upwards. If not bAbajo, it points upwards:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    NSRect contentRect = NSInsetRect([self bounds], LINE_THICKNESS, LINE_THICKNESS);
    NSBezierPath *path = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
    if (_bAbajo)
    {
      [path removeAllPoints];
      [path moveToPoint:NSMakePoint(_arrowX, NSMinY(contentRect))];
      [path lineToPoint:NSMakePoint(_arrowX + ARROW_WIDTH / 2, NSMinY(contentRect) + ARROW_HEIGHT)];
      [path lineToPoint:NSMakePoint(NSMaxX(contentRect) - CORNER_RADIUS, NSMinY(contentRect) + ARROW_HEIGHT)];
      NSPoint bottomRightCorner = NSMakePoint(NSMaxX(contentRect), NSMinY(contentRect) + ARROW_HEIGHT);
      [path curveToPoint:NSMakePoint(NSMaxX(contentRect), NSMinY(contentRect) + ARROW_HEIGHT + CORNER_RADIUS)
         controlPoint1:bottomRightCorner controlPoint2:bottomRightCorner];
      [path lineToPoint:NSMakePoint(NSMaxX(contentRect), NSMaxY(contentRect) - CORNER_RADIUS)];
      NSPoint topRightCorner = NSMakePoint(NSMaxX(contentRect), NSMaxY(contentRect));
      [path curveToPoint:NSMakePoint(NSMaxX(contentRect) - CORNER_RADIUS, NSMaxY(contentRect) + CORNER_RADIUS) controlPoint1:topRightCorner controlPoint2:topRightCorner];
      [path lineToPoint:NSMakePoint(NSMinX(contentRect) + CORNER_RADIUS, NSMaxY(contentRect) + CORNER_RADIUS)];
      NSPoint topLeftCorner = NSMakePoint(NSMinX(contentRect), NSMaxY(contentRect));
      [path curveToPoint:NSMakePoint(NSMinX(contentRect), NSMaxY(contentRect) - CORNER_RADIUS) controlPoint1:topLeftCorner controlPoint2:topLeftCorner];
      [path lineToPoint:NSMakePoint(NSMinX(contentRect), NSMinY(contentRect) + CORNER_RADIUS + ARROW_HEIGHT)];
      NSPoint bottomLeftCorner = NSMakePoint(NSMinX(contentRect), NSMinY(contentRect) + ARROW_HEIGHT);
      [path curveToPoint:NSMakePoint(NSMinX(contentRect) + CORNER_RADIUS, NSMinY(contentRect) + ARROW_HEIGHT) controlPoint1:bottomLeftCorner controlPoint2:bottomLeftCorner];
      [path lineToPoint:NSMakePoint(_arrowX - ARROW_WIDTH/2, NSMinY(contentRect) + ARROW_HEIGHT)];
    }
    else
    {
      [path removeAllPoints];
      [path moveToPoint:NSMakePoint(_arrowX, NSMaxY(contentRect))];
      [path lineToPoint:NSMakePoint(_arrowX + ARROW_WIDTH / 2, NSMaxY(contentRect) - ARROW_HEIGHT)];
      [path lineToPoint:NSMakePoint(NSMaxX(contentRect) - CORNER_RADIUS, NSMaxY(contentRect) - ARROW_HEIGHT)];
      NSPoint topRightCorner = NSMakePoint(NSMaxX(contentRect), NSMaxY(contentRect) - ARROW_HEIGHT);
      [path curveToPoint:NSMakePoint(NSMaxX(contentRect), NSMaxY(contentRect) - ARROW_HEIGHT - CORNER_RADIUS)
           controlPoint1:topRightCorner controlPoint2:topRightCorner];
      [path lineToPoint:NSMakePoint(NSMaxX(contentRect), NSMinY(contentRect) + CORNER_RADIUS)];
      NSPoint bottomRightCorner = NSMakePoint(NSMaxX(contentRect), NSMinY(contentRect));
      [path curveToPoint:NSMakePoint(NSMaxX(contentRect) - CORNER_RADIUS, NSMinY(contentRect))
           controlPoint1:bottomRightCorner controlPoint2:bottomRightCorner];
      [path lineToPoint:NSMakePoint(NSMinX(contentRect) + CORNER_RADIUS, NSMinY(contentRect))];
      [path curveToPoint:NSMakePoint(NSMinX(contentRect), NSMinY(contentRect) + CORNER_RADIUS)
           controlPoint1:contentRect.origin controlPoint2:contentRect.origin];
      [path lineToPoint:NSMakePoint(NSMinX(contentRect), NSMaxY(contentRect) - ARROW_HEIGHT - CORNER_RADIUS)];
      NSPoint topLeftCorner = NSMakePoint(NSMinX(contentRect), NSMaxY(contentRect) - ARROW_HEIGHT);
      [path curveToPoint:NSMakePoint(NSMinX(contentRect) + CORNER_RADIUS, NSMaxY(contentRect) - ARROW_HEIGHT)
           controlPoint1:topLeftCorner controlPoint2:topLeftCorner];
      [path lineToPoint:NSMakePoint(_arrowX - ARROW_WIDTH / 2, NSMaxY(contentRect) - ARROW_HEIGHT)];
    }
    [path closePath];
    [[NSColor colorWithDeviceWhite:1 alpha:FILL_OPACITY] setFill];
    [path fill];
    //[NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];

    NSBezierPath *clip = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:[self bounds]];
    [clip appendBezierPath:path];
    [clip addClip];

    [path setLineWidth:LINE_THICKNESS * 2];
    [[NSColor whiteColor] setStroke];
    [path stroke];

    [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
}
```

On the first time drawRect is called, everything works fine, the drawing goes the way it should depending on the bAbajo boolean. After that, if I call the drawRect again with the opposite value of bAbajo, the right code is executed (bAbajo has the expected value and by debugging with breakpoints I can see that it is executing the right code inside drawRect), but the window is not updated with the new NSBezierPath *path. Any help?

Comment: What happens if you clear the window before doing any drawing?

Comment: What do you mean by "if I call drawRect again?" You never call drawRect directly. Do you mean "when drawRect is called by the system, after I call setNeedsDisplay?"

Comment: Yes, you are right, I meant 'when it is called by the system after I call setNeedsDisplay'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, Rob indirectly gave me the answer, I was not calling the setNeedsDisplay after setting bAbajo.